# assigning Null to the get set method of the class but does not assign null

Tags: c#, asp.net

At the time of login values are stored in the method of a class "Estb_detail" but at the logout time i even assign null to those methods but they does not get empty and remains populated with the same values.

On the next login it again return the old values which are not required.

Estb_detail.cs:

```
public class Estb_detail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Estb_detail()
    {

    }


    private string estbName;

    public string EstbName
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application.Contents["estbName"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("estbName", value); }
    }
    private string estbEmail;

    public string EstbEmail
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application.Contents["estbEmail"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("estbEmail", value); }
    }
    private string companyId;

    public string CompanyId
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application.Contents["companyId"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("companyId", value); }
    }

    private string type_account;

    public string Type_Account
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application.Contents["type_account"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("type_account", value); }
    }    
}
```

Login.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Login : Estb_detail
{
 protected void _btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    using (Estb_cntxtDataContext context = new Estb_cntxtDataContext())
                {
                        var user = (from a in context.tblCustomers where a.Email == _txtName.Text && a.Password == _txtPassword.Text select a).FirstOrDefault();


                        if (user != null)
                        {                    
                            Session["Establishment"] = user.Name;
                            EstbName = user.Name;
                            EstbEmail = user.Email;
                            CompanyId = user.nCompany_Id.ToString();
                            Type_Account = "Master";

                            Response.Redirect("Establishment_Controller.aspx");
                        }
               }
   }
}
```

Establishment_controller.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Establishment_Controller : Estb_detail
{
  protected void _Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();

        EstbName = "";
        EstbEmail = "";
        CompanyId = "";
        Type_Account = "";
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `HttpApplicationState.Add()` multiple times with the same key will add multiple values rather than overwriting the existing value.

http://codeverge.com/asp.net.state-management/httpapplicationstate-allows-duplicat/307305

In the setter, you will need to check if the value already exists and if it does, change its value using the array access operator. Alternatively, use `.Remove()` to remove the key before adding it.